# Rotate an object diagonally and prevent it from going back to 90,180,0,360 degrees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After holding down on a combination keys of AS,SD,DW or WA to move my object, it will successfully move diagonally and rotate to the correct position, but after releasing the keys, it will rotate back to either 0,90,180 or 360 depending on the nearest rotation after releasing my keys, I guess it's because of that 1 frame that I left the keys touched, so it ran that code and moved it to 0,90,180,360. But I don't know how to solve it.

I hope I've provided enough information, and thanks for helping out.
[image]

**I'm pressing onto AW keys together**
[image]

**After releasing the keys, it doesn't stay that way but moves to either left or top**

PlayerMovement.cs

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

     private float speedWalk = 7.5f;
     private float speedRotate = 7.5f;
     private GameObject raycastObject;

     // Update is called once per frame
     void FixedUpdate ()
     {
         //Non-Diagonal Movements
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) //player movement up
         {
             transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, speedWalk * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) //player movement down
         {
             transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, speedWalk * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) //player movement right
         {
             transform.localPosition += new Vector3(speedWalk * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) //player movement left
         {
             transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(speedWalk * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
         }

         //Diagonal Movements **@@@@@@@@** I think this is the problem.
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) //player movement Top Left
         {
             transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(speedWalk * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
             transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, speedWalk * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) //player movement Top Right
         {
             transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, speedWalk * Time.deltaTime);
             transform.localPosition += new Vector3(speedWalk * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) //player movement Bottom Right
         {
             transform.localPosition += new Vector3(speedWalk * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
             transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, speedWalk * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) //player movement Bottom Left
         {
             transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, speedWalk * Time.deltaTime);
             transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(speedWalk * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
         }
     }
 }
```

playerRotateMouse.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class playerRotateMouse : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public Transform Player;
     private float speed = 7.5f;
     Quaternion targetRotation;

     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         Plane playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);

         // Generates a ray from cursor
         Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

         float hitdist = 0.0f;

         if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") || Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
         {
             if (playerPlane.Raycast(ray, out hitdist))
             {
                 Vector3 targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
                 Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, targetPoint, Color.green);
                 targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint - transform.position);
             }
         }
         // Smooth rotation towards point.
         transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);

         //Rotate base on key pressed
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && !(Input.GetButton("Fire1") || Input.GetButton("Fire2"))) //player rotate up
         {
             targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward);
             transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && !(Input.GetButton("Fire1") || Input.GetButton("Fire2"))) //player rotate down
         {
             targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward * -1);
             transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && !(Input.GetButton("Fire1") || Input.GetButton("Fire2"))) //player rotate right
         {
             targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.right);
             transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && !(Input.GetButton("Fire1") || Input.GetButton("Fire2"))) //player rotate left
         {
             targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.left);
             transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: If you release both keys, they will probably not be released 100% at the same time. So it will point to the angle of the last released key. I guess.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed that, but I couldn't think of any other way to go around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would save a last timestamp, and check if the second key release is within a certain timeframe. If it is release within (for example) 20ms, don't reset it is pressed.

For example:  (pseudo)

```
private bool[] _directionKeysPressed = new bool[4];
private DateTime _previousKeyRelease;

private void KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _keyPressedCount++;

    switch(keys)
    {
       case(W): _directionKeysPressed[0] = true;
       case(D): _directionKeysPressed[1] = true;
       // .................
    }
}

private void KeyUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _keyPressedCount--;

    if(_keyPressedCount == 0)
    {
        // all keys released
        _directionKeysPressed[] <--- last direction...

        // reset all bools
        return;
    }

    // ONLY if the key is released outside the 20 ms, reset the key.
    if(_previousKeyRelease.AddMilliseconds(20) < DateTime.UTCNow)
    {  // RESET KEY
        switch(keys)
        {
            case(W): _directionKeysPressed[0] = false;
            case(D): _directionKeysPressed[1] = false;
            // .................
        }
    }

    _previousKeyRelease = DateTime.UTCNow;
}
```

Personally I would do this with an bitfield in a Int32, but it is more clear with an array of bool.

Comment: I fiddled around with the TimeStamp that you mentioned and sort of got it to work, thanks alot!